# Reverse string script giving runtime error

Tags: c++, string, reference, compiler-errors

I have tried my best to fix my logic, but I can't detect the error. I can't use [] or any other advance features, as I haven't covered them yet. If you can, please tell me my mistake.Please don't give me negative points because I have tried my hardest, and my error doesn't make sense! Thanks.

This script is supposed to reverse the input string: for example: hi to ih.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void ReverseString(string &aString);

int main(){
    string info;
    cout << "What's your string?" << endl;
    getline(cin, info);
    cout << info << " compare with: " << endl;
    ReverseString(info);
    cout << info << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void ReverseString(string &aString)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++)
    {

        int u = aString.length() - 1 - i;
        string temp = "";
        temp += aString.at(aString.length() - 1 - i); 
        if(u == 0 )/* when aString.length() - 1 - i == 0, the last char will have been processed*/
        {
        aString = temp; /*store temp into aString; when its value changes, it is passed     into info's value*/
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: `[]` is _not_ an advanced feature.  You should be using it long before you've ever heard of `at()`.  (Of course, the "advanced" way of reversing a string would be to call `std::reverse` on it.  But unlike `[]`, I can understand that being banned for the moment.)

Comment: thank you. But do you see the error in my logic?

Comment: `string temp = ""` is in the wrong place. That's the logic error. You have to learn to read the code you write and see it how it really is.

Comment: @NewProgrammer Just that it's way too complicated.  If you do want to use a temporary string, something like `int i = aString.size(); while ( i > 0 ) { -- i; temp += aString[ i ]; }` would be the most natural solution (with `temp` declared before the loop, of course).

Comment: lol, thank you for that; but your code seems too complex to me in retrospect, for that's your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that every time you run through your for loop in `ReverseString()`, you're re-initializing your `temp` variable, deleting everything you've already saved in the string. Your program works as expected if I do this to the ReverseString function:

```
void ReverseString(string &aString)
    string temp = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++)
    {

        int u = aString.length() - 1 - i;
        temp += aString.at(aString.length() - 1 - i); 
        if(u == 0 )/* when aString.length() - 1 - i == 0, the last char will have been processed*/
        {
        aString = temp; /*store temp into aString; when its value changes, it is passed     into info's value*/
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep it simple, what you want is to look at the last character of the old string and put it at the end of the new string. So instead of looping from 0 to end, you loop from end to 0. But you should declare your new string before the loop because if you do it inside the loop you will always throw the contents away after each iteration.

```
string newString;
for(int i = aString.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    newString.append(aString.at(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The classical idiom involves swapping, and maintaining two
indices:

```
void
ReverseString( std::string& target )
{
    int bottom = 0;
    int top = target.size();
    while ( top > bottom ) {
        -- top;
        char tmp = target[top];
        target[top] = target[bottom];
        target[bottom] = tmp;
        ++ bottom;
    }
}
```

(In practice, I'd use `std::swap` in the loop, but I imagine
that that's also banned.)

This does the job in place, and avoids the extra intermediate
string.